# JavaScript Traffic Light Sequence: The value of the property 'Timer' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, timer

I'm currently working on a piece of coursework for Computer Science where we need to automate a traffic light sequence using buttons e.g "Traffic Lights On" or "Traffic Lights off". When I run my program through the internet explorer debugger, I get the error code: "The value of the property 'Timer' is null or undefined, not a Function object" on line 5 of my coding even though I've defined it as a function later on in the script. My programming can be found below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>
    <button type="button" onclick="Timer()"> Start Lights</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="StopTimer()"> Stop lights</button>
</p>

<img id = "TrafficLight" src="http://imgur.com/FHT9OoG.jpg">
<script>
var TrafficLightList = [
    "http://imgur.com/FHT9OoG.jpg",
    "http://imgur.com/XZ1PxGh.jpg",
    "http://imgur.com/5DUX0Wy.jpg",
    "http://imgur.com/WpeEMZU.jpg"
];
var Automation = 0;
var TimeBetweenChange = null;

function ChangeLightAutomated() {
    if(Automation == TrafficLightList.length) Automation = 0;
    var Light = document.getElementById("TrafficLight");
    image.src = TrafficLightList[Automation];
    image.alt = TrafficLightList[Automation] //debugger
    Automation = Automation + 1;
}

function Timer() {
    if(!TimeBetweenChange) {
        TimeBetweenChange = self.setTimeBetweenChange(ChangeLightAutomated,     1000);
  }
}

function StopTimer() {
    self.clearTimeBetweenChange(TimeBetweenChange);
    TimeBetweenChange = null;
}

</body>
</script>
</html>
```

As I've said before, the error appears to be on line 5 of the program as "Timer" is not defined even though I define what Timer's function is on line 28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several undefined variables in your code, for example you do `var Light = document.getElementById("TrafficLight");` and then `image.src = TrafficLightList[Automation];` in which case `image` is undefined. Also, there's no `self` defined anywhere.

Here's a working example of what you wanted to do:

```js
var timer = (function () {
    var trafficLightList = [
        "http://imgur.com/FHT9OoG.jpg",
        "http://imgur.com/XZ1PxGh.jpg",
        "http://imgur.com/5DUX0Wy.jpg",
        "http://imgur.com/WpeEMZU.jpg"
    ];
    var automation = 0;
    var interval = null;

    function changeLightAutomated() {
        if(automation == trafficLightList.length) automation = 0;
        var image = document.getElementById("TrafficLight");
        image.src = trafficLightList[automation];
        image.alt = trafficLightList[automation] //debugger
        ++automation;
    }

    function startTimer() {
        interval = setInterval(changeLightAutomated, 1000);
    }


    function stopTimer() {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }

    return {
        start: startTimer,
        stop: stopTimer
    }
})()

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function() {timer.start()})
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function() {timer.stop()})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>
    <button type="button" id="start"> Start Lights</button>
    <button type="button" id="stop"> Stop lights</button>
</p>

<img id = "TrafficLight" src="http://imgur.com/FHT9OoG.jpg">
<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Add ID's to the buttons:**

```
<input type="button" id="button1_id" value="Some description" onclick="Timer()">
<input type="button" id="button1_id" value="Some description" onclick="StopTimer()">
```

*I added a value too, so the button has text inside. Change 'Some description' to some suggestive text*

**And then, for each one do (on javascript):**

```
var timerSelector = document.getElementById("button1_id");
timerSelector.onclick = Timer;

var stopTimerSelector = document.getElementById("button2_id");
stopTimerSelector.onclick = StopTimer;
```

or simply:

```
document.getElementById("button1_id").onclick= Timer;
document.getElementById("button2_id").onclick = StopTimer;
```

Add these lines to the javascript.

Let me know if it solved the problem.